# Unable to insert values in second row : Android TableLayout

Tags: java, android

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        TableLayout tableLayout;
        TextView[] textViewArray = new TextView[5];
        TableRow[] tableRowArray = new TableRow[5];

        TableRow tr1,tr2,tr3,tr4,tr5;
        Course_Factory cf = new Course_Factory();
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            tableLayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table);

            for(int j =0 ;j<5;j++)
            {
                tableRowArray[j]=new TableRow(this);//Creating 5 textViews
                textViewArray[j] = new TextView(this);//Creating 5 rows
                tableLayout.setColumnStretchable(j,true);
            }

            Button button =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override

                public void onClick(View view) {
                    EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);//searching the course by it's id.
                    int id= Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());

                    LinkedList<Course> courses = cf.getCourses(id);

                        for (Course c:courses)
                            {
                                if(c.getId()==id)//checking if id matches or not
                                {
                                        textViewArray[0].setText("1");
                                        textViewArray[1].setText(c.getTitile());
                                        String credit = new Integer(c.getCredit()).toString();
                                        textViewArray[2].setText(credit);
                                        String tpc = new Integer(c.getTuitionPerCredit()).toString();
                                        textViewArray[3].setText(tpc);
                                        String st = new Integer(c.getSubtotal()).toString();
                                        textViewArray[4].setText(st);


                                     int i =0;
                                        tableRowArray[i].addView(textViewArray[0]);
                                        tableRowArray[i].addView(textViewArray[1]);
                                        tableRowArray[i].addView(textViewArray[2]);
                                        tableRowArray[i].addView(textViewArray[3]);
                                        tableRowArray[i].addView(textViewArray[4]);
                                        tableLayout.addView(tableRowArray[i]);
                                }
                            }
                }

            });

        }
    }
```

I have already added some courses in another class in a linked list. when i try to search one course by its id it shows in the first row but i don't understand how can i go to the second row. i have tried several things but it didn't work. Please help me!

Comment: Where do you change the value of variable "i"?

Comment: tableRowArray[i].addView(textViewArray[0]);
                                        tableRowArray[i].addView(textViewArray[1]);
                                        tableRowArray[i].addView(textViewArray[2]);
                                        tableRowArray[i].addView(textViewArray[3]);
                                        tableRowArray[i].addView(textViewArray[4]);
                                        tableLayout.addView(tableRowArray[i]);

Comment: I want it to show the details on the second row after i am done with the first course and first row. But i am unable to do it. I manually fixed the value of "i" =0 to see if it works. now i want to go to the second row. Please help me

Comment: What happens if you put: i++; after tableLayout.addView(tableRowArray[i]);

Comment: i tried that too. It shows an error which says this child already has a parent and you must call removeView() and then I tried to look for code of this function in stackOverflow but could not understand how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question (you need explain what your question clearer, what you're doing etc) but this code:

```
int i =0;
tableRowArray[i].addView(textViewArray[0]);
tableRowArray[i].addView(textViewArray[1]);
tableRowArray[i].addView(textViewArray[2]);
tableRowArray[i].addView(textViewArray[3]);
tableRowArray[i].addView(textViewArray[4]);
tableLayout.addView(tableRowArray[i]);
```

will always insert your first table row unless you change the value of `i`. If `i` = `1` then it'd create your second row.

Are you after something like the below?

```
EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);//searching the course by it's id.
int id= Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());

int i =0;
LinkedList<Course> courses = cf.getCourses(id);

for (Course c:courses)
{
    if(c.getId()==id)//checking if id matches or not
    {
        textViewArray[0].setText("1");
        textViewArray[1].setText(c.getTitile());
        String credit = new Integer(c.getCredit()).toString();
        textViewArray[2].setText(credit);
        String tpc = new Integer(c.getTuitionPerCredit()).toString();
        textViewArray[3].setText(tpc);
        String st = new Integer(c.getSubtotal()).toString();
        textViewArray[4].setText(st);

    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this); // You can set the orientation of this as desired using setOrientation
    ll.addView(textViewArray[0]);
    ll.addView(textViewArray[1]);
    ll.addView(textViewArray[2]);
    ll.addView(textViewArray[3]);
    ll.addView(textViewArray[4]);       
    tableRowArray[i].addView(ll);
    i++;
    }
}
```

Notice, I've moved the `i` variable outside the loop and increment in the loop. Is that what you're after?

Comment: In this section of my code I am adding textView with values in my first row. Now my question is exactly what you said. I can not find out what to do to change the value of "i" so that when i search for a new course it gets added to the second row. I tried to use loop but id didn't work.

Comment: Updated my answer. Not sure if it helps?!

Comment: I tried this and it shows this error : "The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first" :(.

Comment: Oh, that's because you're adding multiple textview's to a `TableRow`. They need to be in a container view like `LinearLayout`, and add your `TextView`'s to that view instead.

Comment: But it works totally fine in the first time. The problem gets started when i search for a new course second time. so I don't think i need to change the whole structure and moreover i have used Relative Layout in my xml file. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help guys but I got the solution. I needed to create the rows and textView Dynamically instead I was trying to create them before entering the value in the rows, here is the solution.
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
    TableLayout tableLayout;
    TableRow tr ;
    TextView tv1,tv2,tv3,tv4,tv5;
    Course_Factory cf = new Course_Factory();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tableLayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table);


        Button button =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override

            public void onClick(View view) {

             addData();

     }
        });


    }

    public void addData()
    {
        EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);
        int id= Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());

        LinkedList<Course> courses = cf.getCourses(id);



            for (Course c : courses) {

                if (c.getId() == id) {

                        tr = new TableRow(this);
                        tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                    tv1 = new TextView(this);
                    tv1.setText("1");
                    tr.addView(tv1);

                    tv2 = new TextView(this);
                    tv2.setText(c.getTitile());
                    tr.addView(tv2);

                    tv3 = new TextView(this);
                        String credit = new Integer(c.getCredit()).toString();
                        tv3.setText(credit);
                        tr.addView(tv3);

                        tv4 = new TextView(this);
                        String tpc = new Integer(c.getTuitionPerCredit()).toString();
                        tv4.setText(tpc);
                        tr.addView(tv4);

                        tv5 = new TextView(this);
                        String st = new Integer(c.getSubtotal()).toString();
                        tv5.setText(st);
                        tr.addView(tv5);



                         tableLayout.addView(tr);
                }


        }
    }


}
```